# Programmatically copy in-use files

Tags: c#, copy, shadow-copy, file-in-use

In my C# code I want to be able to use some Shadow Copy mechanism in order to copy files that are being used by another process.

I've seen that solutions exist on the web, in enterprise or command line tools. But could it be done programmatically in order to mimic a simple file copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [alphavss](http://alphavss.alphaleonis.com/) does what you want. The sample file `VssBackup.cs` [here](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaVSS/tree/master/src/Samples/VssBackup) seems to do exactly what you want.

> This class encapsulates some simple VSS logic. Its goal is to allow a user to backup a single file from a shadow copy (presumably because that file is otherwise unavailable on its home volume).